# How do primary constructors, secondary constructors and class members interact with each other in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, constructor

I've looked at the [official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html) and the questions related to this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44843741/kotlin-constructors-primary-and-secondary) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51011574/why-each-secondary-constructor-needs-to-delegate-to-the-primary-constructor-in-k). The answers within rephrase the documentation without explaining the link between the three.

In code I've seen so far, the class members rely on the arguments in the primary constructor to be implemented. Everything works fine and makes sense.

The secondary constructor comes along and I don't see how they all work together. For example, one concept I don't understand is how class members make use of the secondary constructor.

I would like someone to explain how the primary constructor, secondary constructor and class members interact and why secondary constructors are beneficial in a real-world example.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the class members rely on the arguments in the primary constructor to be implemented

They don't; only property initializers and `init` blocks can use these arguments (if they are not also available as properties), but methods can't.

> For example, one concept I don't understand is how class members make use of the secondary constructor.

They don't; every secondary constructor has to call the primary constructor (that's why it's called primary) and the initializers/`init` blocks will use the arguments from the primary constructor call.

> why secondary constructors are beneficial in a real-world example

Because they can provide another way to construct an instance of the class? I am not sure what you are looking for beyond that. For an example, see the constructors of `ArrayList`:

```
<init>(initialCapacity: Int)
<init>(elements: Collection<E>)
```

Comment: So, the secondary constructor gives the primary constructor arguments using the `this` keyword and the following parenthesis? Does the compiler infer which constructor to use based on the arguments you give? Why would programmers decide an alternate way to construct an instance necessary or why is the primary constructor not good enough for whatever the application is?

Comment: 1. Yes, primary or another secondary, it just has to bottom out at the primary constructor. 2. Yes, using the same rules as for method overloading. 3. For the same reason they would decide any other members are necessary (or just useful).