# Understanding secondary constructor in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I don't understand the use of `this` and how the object is created or constructor is called and what's happening in the below code.

```
class Person {
    var children: MutableList<Person> = mutableListOf<Person>();
    constructor(parent: Person) {
        parent.children.add(this)
    }
}

class Person(val name: String) {
    var children: MutableList<Person> = mutableListOf<Person>();
    constructor(name: String, parent: Person) : this(name) {
        parent.children.add(this)
    }
}
```

source : https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51011574/why-each-secondary-constructor-needs-to-delegate-to-the-primary-constructor-in-k

Comment: So... what don't you understand in the exlanations on the linked page?

Comment: When u create Person A, do you have to pass a another Person B object to the Person A constructor.  What does parent.children.add(this) do ? Can you give me one example how the object is created.

Comment: If you call the secondary constructor, yes, since it expects a Person as argument. `parent.children.add(this)` adds the current object, being constructed (this) to the children of the parent person passed as argument. Example: `val francis = Person("Francis Ford Coppola") val sofia = Person(name = "Sofia Coppola", parent = francis)`. After that, franciis's children list contains sofia.

Comment: That's because you're trying to use the first version of Person, which doesn't have a primary constructor with a name. Use the second one.

Comment: Thanks... I understood

Comment: Also `"Francis Ford Coppola"` doesn't mean anything, because there is no property in the class that stores that. right ? What does `: this(name)`  in the constructor represents ? that syntax means its returning that right ?

Comment: @Fone In kotlin, constructor params become member properties. So, in this case "Francis Ford Coppola" gets set to the `name` property. The `: this(name)` means that the secondary constructor calls the primary constructor and passes in the name param.

Comment: @MattBerteaux Thank u :) Primary constructors are called before secondary constructors right ?

Comment: @Fone: `val name: String`: that defines a primary constructor argument named `name`, and since it's prefixed with `val`, it also defines an immutable property named `name`. And as explained in the documentation you linked to, `this(name)` means that the secondary constructor, which also takes an argument named `name`, calls the primary constructor with that argument.

Answer (score 0):

`: this(...)` call means call to another constructor, so each object was constructed with the primary constructor too.

```kotlin
class Person /* a */ (val name: String) {
    var children: MutableList<Person> = mutableListOf<Person>();
    /* b */ constructor(name: String, parent: Person) : this(name) {
        parent.children.add(this)
    }
}
```

In this example, there is primary constructor after `a`, and secondary one after `b`, so there are two ways to instantiate this class.

1. Call the primary constructor: `Person("abc")`.
2. Call the secondary constructor: `Person("abc", Person("dfg"))`, and it is guaranteed that both primary and secondary constructor will be called.